# How can I silence `rustc`'s note about which native artifacts to link against?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I've got a project where Rust source files are being automatically generated and compiled into static libraries. I'd like the output of `rustc` to be streamed to stdout and stderr as usual, but I wish that the following note wasn't always emitted:

```
note: link against the following native artifacts when linking against this static library

note: the order and any duplication can be significant on some platforms, and so may need to be preserved

note: library: System

note: library: resolv

note: library: c

note: library: m
```

Is there any way to silence this without silencing too much else? The note was useful to me when I was figuring out how to link things automatically, but it won't be useful to my users who never actually see the linking process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rust 1.21 and earlier, there is no way to turn off the output.

In Rust 1.22, the `--print=native-static-libs` option was added. When it is not present, it outputs:

> note: This list will not be printed by default. Please add --print native-static-libs if you need this information.

Adding the option will silence the warning.

To silence this information without silencing anything else, upgrade to Rust 1.23 once it's released.

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/43067

Comment: To be clear, you are saying that to solve the problem, the OP should basically *just* wait until Rust 1.23? The bit about the option is basically how to get the Rust 1.21 behavior back in a future Rust 1.23?

Comment: I've actually since stumbled across the PR that implemented this change. You've summarized everything very well. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Shepmaster. The OP should just wait.